# cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. on Mac Ventura 13.2.1

Tags: macos, terminal

I have tried to open an app from a trusted 3rd party in my Mac.

But my Mac in not allowing to open it with a message `"cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified."`

Answer (score 0):

Click on `Apple icon` -> `System settings…` -> It will open System settings app.

Now, Click on `Privacy & Security`->  `Developer Tools` -> `Enable` the switch beside `Terminal`

Finally! Now, it will ask your Mac system password. Provide the your system password.

You are all set to open your required apps using terminal !!!.